# Установить анимацию на программный dismiss BottomSheetDialogFragment'а

Tags: java, android, анимация

Господа, вопрос скорее всего простой, но при гуглении кидает на "кастомные анимации".
Есть BottomSheetDialogFragment  который открывается и скрывается программно из кода.
Открытие:

```
bottomFragment.show(getParentFragmentManager(),"ModalButtomSheet");
```

Закрытие:

```
bottomFragment.dismiss();
```

Однако открывается он со стандартной анимацией (всплывает).
А закрывается без анимации - просто пропадает.
Задача: сделать так, чтобы он закрывался с такой же стандартной анимацией (уплывал вниз за экран).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить анимацию можно таким способом (на примере фрагмента):

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onActivityCreated(arg0);
    getDialog().getWindow()
    .getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
}
```

и вот анимация в стилях:

```
<style name="DialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_down</item>
</style>
```

[и вот есть](https://proandroiddev.com/android-bottom-sheet-behavior-and-animated-button-on-top-of-it-da86a9bfe545) так же статья по данному вопросу. [Вот документация](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/reveal-or-hide-view) по вопросу анимации.

Comment: Спасибо. Это работает.